# Pressing enter on child modal dialog fires enter on parent modal dialog (ie11 and edge)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap modal dialog windows, one creates  the other.  When enter is pressed on the child's text input it fires an event on the parent as well.  The last button to have focus on the parent was the one to create the child, this causes the child to be recreated immediately.

I have found some similar problems which state to make sure the ok buttons on the dialog are of type=button since they default to submit.  I have made sure that the buttons have the type of button but the issue persists, though it works fine in chrome.

Here an example of what is happening in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/smeHL3jXB64vLrIkGeTZ?p=preview).
This is the first modal window.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="shownewwindow()">New Modal</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

And here is the second.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal2.html">
        <div class="modal-body">
           <input type=textarea value="test" ng-keypress="keydown($event)" autofocus></input>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="ok()">ok</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Here are the functions for ok, cancel, and keydown.

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    console.log("ok");
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss({completed: true});
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  $scope.keydown = function(event) {
            var enterKeyCode = 13;
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss({completed: true});
  }
```

Any ideas on how to prevent the child from being created repeatedly when enter is pressed would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to post your code for anyone to be able to give you any sort of answer.

Comment: My apologies, here is an example in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/smeHL3jXB64vLrIkGeTZ?p=preview) of what is going on.  Upon further inspection while making this example I found that the enter key press is actually coming from an input field on the child.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the button when you click on it.

```
<button ng-disabled="aScopeVar" ng-click="setAScopeVarToTrue()">My button</button>
```

Don't forget to set `aScopeVar` to true after the child is created.